# Use awk to swap two set of word(s) seperated by a given string

Tags: awk

In my input file, each line has two word(s) separated by the string 'swap'. 
I need to swap the word(s) before 'swap' with the word(s) after 'swap' from each line.

Input: 'cat myfile.txt'

```
world swap hello
hoo swap woo 
I'm cooler swap You're cool
```

Expected Output:

```
hello swap world
woo swap hoo
You're cool swap I'm cooler
```

Is it additionally possible to replace 'swap' with '-' in the output like:

```
hello - world
woo - hoo
You're cool - I'm cooler
```

Comment: It always amazes me when people post a question and immediately accept the first answer they get that produces the expected output from some small sample input set. It's almost always the wrong answer, such as in this case, and will fail later given some other input. Getting the expected output from some small sample input is the **starting** point for identifying a solution, not the end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`awk -F"swap" '{print $2 " - " $1 }' myfile.txt`

Comment: Try that with input like `this swap will fail when swapping` to see it fail.

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk -F" +swap +" '{print $NF,"-",$1}'  Input_file
```

Comment: That's better than the currently accepted answer but it'll still fail when `swap` appears at the start or end of the line.

Comment: Yeah I knew that but was lazy to update it with the spaces. However the original post does have a mention of swap between two words all the time with spaces between them so it should work.

Comment: @asatsi I assume your comment here is actually intended to be under your answer. No it won't work because `swap` can be part of another word like `swapping` and in tat case it should not be used to split the record into further fields. See my comment under your answer.